# How to edit a wordpress theme to autoload products rather than paginate products

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

A wordpress theme(Revo) l am using displays products in pages and links the pages with pagination but my client wants the products to be autoloaded as the user scrolls.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please visit the help center and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

I've used this plugin before, it does exactly what you need.

For your use case, WooCommerce products, see this documentation with examples and code: https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/examples/woocommerce/

Comment: can you show how to use this plugin with woocommerce because the page l want to use ajax load more is been generated by woocommerce

Comment: @firefire a quick google gave me directions for using it with WooCommerce - edited my answer :)